# df Not Showing NFS "Stale File Handle" in Debian Buster

Tags: debian, ubuntu, nfs, disk-usage, proxmox

I periodically run into NFS "stale file handle" errors on my Proxmox server (usually from when I have to reboot my NFS server which is to be expected).

I have [a script](https://github.com/Torqu3Wr3nch/nfsStaleFileHandleDestroyer/blob/master/staleHandleDestroyer) that I run as a cron job to automatically detect NFS stale file mounts and lazy umount them which relies on `df 2>&1 | grep 'Stale file handle'`.

It works great in my Ubuntu VMs, however, when I run this same script directly on my Proxmox host, which itself has NFS mounts, the script doesn't work. I have determined that this is due to an apparent difference in output with `df 2>&1` in Proxmox/Debian Buster (which I know sounds crazy). In Proxmox, the output of `df 2>&1` does not show a stale file handle error when I do in fact have one (determined by navigating to /mnt/pve/unraid and running lsof which does return the stale file handle error):

[image: NFS Mount on unRAID. This NFS mount is stale, but it isn't appearing as so with df]

**Question:** Why is `df` not reporting the stale file handle error on Proxmox/Debian Buster while it does on Ubuntu?

Thank you in advance!

---

Additional Notes for Reference: [Fixing NFS/SMB Stale File Handle Errors in Proxmox: Automatic Detection Script](https://forums.engineerworkshop.com/t/fixing-nfs-smb-stale-file-handle-errors-in-proxmox-automatic-detection-script/213?u=torquewrench)